# Marketo - How to get the mandatory fields information in leads database

Tags: marketo

I would like to fetch the mandatory fields information in in leads database.
Is there any way to do this

Answer (score 0):

There are no mandatory fields in the Person object in Marketo. If you wanted, you could create records with no information at all. If you just want to get the field names, use the 'describe' call.

```
GET /rest/v1/leads/describe.json
```

For full details, see http://developers.marketo.com/rest-api/lead-database/leads/#describe